# Python: Read from command output

Tags: python, command-line, output, ls

Community,

I want to be able to read the output of a command "isi nfs exports list" into a script/program.

The script/program will then use the data from the output to locate the directory listings within the output.

Use the directory listing and run a ls -lzed [DIRECTORYSTRING] for each line.

This output will allow me to be able to gather who the user and group owner is for each directory.

Comment: have you tried just getting data from stdin like `isi nfs exports list | python myprogram.py`

Comment: @theWanderer4865, is that the same as appending the output to the file "myprogram.py"?

Answer (score 2):

You can call it from python and get the output as a string by using `subprocess.check_output'  [check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
    'Hello World!\n'
```

Comment: Ok, I am new still trying to rap my head around this programming stuff and how to make it useful to me being a systems administrator.  So excuse my ignorance in the questions I ask.  I am trying to figure out bases on what you provided where would my command be inputted?  Would it go in place of "Hello World!"  ?  I get this error when I run the line of code you provided:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
NameError: name 'subprocess' is not defined

Comment: Check the edit. You need to first import the subprocess module. Let me know if it still throws an exception.

Comment: This is embarrassing... I am still getting errors:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hunt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
  File "C:\Users\hunt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
 ...

Comment: Try with `subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"], shell=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. Take a look at a method called `check_output`. It runs a command with given arguments and then returns its output as a byte string.

An example from the documentation:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
'Hello World!\n'
```

Seems like exactly what you're looking for.